# How can I get a tomcat docker image based on rhel7?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The one listed on https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat is based on debian. Where can I get a rhel based image? Or is there a way I can create it by myself.

I am currently working on rhel 7.6 and have docker installed on my machine?

Comment: I don't think there is a Tomcat Docker image based on RHEL, at least in Docker Hub, as RHEL is a licensed software. Is there any specific reason you need Tomcat to run in a RHEL based image?

Comment: You can use Debian based image on your RHEL Docker, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @adam, It is that we have rhel image of tomcat on our production servers. I was looking to replicate some performance issues on my personal machine  which doesn't have access to rhel based image of tomcat used in prod envs. So, I was looking for that on internet. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to build it yourself because RHEL is proprietary and therefore underrepresented in docker hub. You could go for a centos version though, which is almost identical.

Note: RHEL would be considered an extremely unusual choice for a container OS. Are you sure you're doing the right thing? If this is a rule given to you by your employer then it's wrong and you should go fix that instead -- it'll be easier than trying to build rhel containers.

You could take a look at this as a starting point for ideas on how to build it yourself: https://github.com/sclorg/rhscl-dockerfiles/blob/master/centos7.python27/Dockerfile.rhel7

Comment: Enginner, thanks for reply and suggestion. I am following the same now using centos version. Thanks.